# MySQL stores 0.00 as 0?

Tags: mysql, number-formatting

How can we store 0.00 as a float value? The number of decimal places for the column have been set to 2. The column is of float datatype. Whenever I try to insert 0.00, it automatically converts 0.00 to 0.

Comment: Of course it does, why would you think it wouldn't?

Comment: I must be missing something. Last I checked `0.00` is the same value as `0`, which is also the same as `000000.0000000000`. Unless you're trying to somehow indicate the tenths and hundredths places are [*significant*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures). In which case you will have to store this metadata somewhere in the table.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it demonstrates absolutely no understanding of simple datatypes.

Comment: Consider using varchar and store as string.

Answer (score 6):

You're confusing storage with display.

No computer stores 0.00, 0.0, 0.0000, 0000.00000 or any other representation of zero as those ASCII characters; MySQL doesn't store numbers as the strings you input them as. It stores them in an IEEE binary floating-point format that would make next to no sense to you in its native form.

When you see it in human-readable form, the software responsible makes a choice on how to show it to you. There is really no need to see `0.00` rather than `0` but you can configure your query to do that if you wish; it sounds like you may wish to use [`FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format):

```
SELECT FORMAT(`MyColumn`, 2) AS `MyColumnToTwoDecimalPlaces`
```

Answer (score 1):

`0` is the same as `0.00`. They are not stored any differently. Whatever you are using to view the value is doing the truncation. Whatever language you use to retrieve the value should be fully capable of adding trailing zeroes to the specified precision.

Answer (score 0):

In a DECIMAL column declaration, the precision and scale can be (and usually is) specified; for example:

```
salary DECIMAL(5,2)
```

look at [Fixed-Point types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)